# On WS02, rate limit works successfully but the quota does not

Tags: wso2, limit, quota

When setting throttling limits for our API, it appears that the Rate Limit works successfully but the Quota does not.

We created a subscription that limits to 10 requests/second, and when running tests, we obtain a 429 response upon sending an 11th query in one second, which is exactly what we want and expect.

However, the filter also has a Quota of 100 requests/minute, yet we are able to run over 100 requests (have tested up to 300 queries and still gotten entirely 200 response codes) in the span of a minute without getting throttled.

Comment: Explain your deployment. Just a single node?

Comment: In the first case, where the 11th query is throttled out, what is the quota limit defined and what is the Rate Limiting defined in second case?